# Rails4 accessing params and session from gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, parameters

I am building a gem that needs to access GET params and current session.

```
Module MyGem
    class MyClass
        def write_to_session
            session[:user_id] = nil if params[:logout]
        end
    end
end
```

The code above just doesn't work because sessions and params are accessible only in the controller.
In another similar question someone suggested to pass params to the class

```
Module MyGem
    class MyClass
        def initialize(params)
            @params = params
        end

        def write_to_session
            if @params[:param]
                #Do stuff...
            end
        end
    end
```

But I wonder if it's possible to just have those variables without passing them
    end

Comment: Guessing here that the Module is designed for use in a controller? If so, you can inherit from ApplicationController and have the user inherit from your controller in the controllers that need your gem. Or have them include your module into the controllers.

Comment: I think this is related to abstraction. There is no need for the Class to know about params or session object.

Comment: Think of it this way ... let your controllers manage session and http parameters (either via GET or POST). If you need them to be accessed by other elements like models, pass them as parameters in methods. So the controller gives you access to params and session, but in your model you might have class MyClass def do_stuff_w_session(session_object) .... end end

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating a session in a class is fine - it's just another storage location. Better to abstract it and not clutter up the controller code.

Just initialize the class with a session

```
def initialize(session, params)
```

Then do everything you need